# Send an email from a flex app on both android and Iphone

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Using flash builder I have developed an app for both android and IPhone. I would like to be able to open the default email client on the phone and send an email with an attachment. I have seen many examples using "mailto:" however this is not supported with an attachment. I have googled this extensively and have found nothing that is current with in the last 3 years.

I already make the pdf file I wish to attach and can move it to a temp directory if needed to satisfy the access issue. I would like to use the default mailer like other programs use if that is not doable please tell me how to directly send an email from the app.

Comment: You need server side code. And to attach file you can upload file using File or FileReference class.

Comment: That is not the only way, and most definitely not what I was asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference to help expand the Action Script 3.0 Information base. I was unable to find any way to do what I was asking above. Here is the Method that I used to send email with attachment. 
https://code.google.com/p/airxmail/
http://flex.coltware.com/as3-flex-air/airxmail/

```
import com.coltware.airxmail.INetAddress;
import com.coltware.airxmail.MailSender.SMTPSender;
import com.coltware.airxmail.MimeMessage;
import com.coltware.airxmail.RecipientType;

private function send_plain_email():void{
//  How to send plain text email
var sender:SMTPSender = new SMTPSender();
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.HOST,"your.smtp.hostname");
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.PORT,25);  // default port is 25
// If you use SMTP-AUTH
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.AUTH,true);
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.USERNAME,"username");
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.PASSWORD,"password");

// Create email message
var message:MimeMessage = new MimeMessage();

//  Set from email address and reciepients
var from:INetAddress = new INetAddress("from-email-address@xxxx.yyyy","from label");
message.setFrom(from);

var toRecpt:INetAddress = new INetAddress("to-email-address@xxxx.yyyy","to label");
message.addRcpt(RecipientType.TO,toRecpt);

var ccRecpt:INetAddress = new INetAddress("cc-email-address@xxxx.yyyy","cc label");
message.addRcpt(RecipientType.CC,ccRecpt);

//  
message.setSubject("hello world");
//
//  Plain Text Part
//
var textPart:MimeTextPart = new MimeTextPart();
message.setSubject("Reciept for #" + job.jobs.JobID);
textPart.contentType.setParameter("charset","UTF-8");
textPart.transferEncoding = "8bit";
textPart.setText("Please see attached PDF \n You will need a PDF viewer to open \n To download the latest version of Adobe Acrobat reader, Please follow the link: http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep.html");
message.addChildPart(textPart);

//
//  Attachment part 
//
    var filePart:MimeImagePart = new MimeImagePart();
    filePart.contentType.setMainType("application");
    filePart.contentType.setSubType("pdf");
           filePart.setAttachementFile(File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(sfile),"WorkOrder.pdf");
            message.addChildPart(filePart);

            sender.send(message);
            sender.close();
}
```